# Creatures which can be mortal in one dimension and immortal in another dimension, How do I avoid time freezing forever?

Tags: magic, physics, time, balancing-magic-systems, spacetime-dimensions

These beings can live a normal life, except they switch dimensions, their body still remains in the same place. But almost as if time froze, they are transported in another world, an infinite landscape and all the creatures can do in this dimension is wait and think about their past.
While in the second dimension the creatures are immortal and live forever, since time is frozen in the real dimension one could spend eternity in the secondary dimension and never age.

A child could go in the secondary dimension for a few millenia then come back as an adult thousands of years old but in the body of a child, surprised to see their parents again after so many millenia.
When the creatures die in the first dimension, they also die in the second dimension.

**Question**:
What rules should I add to retain the sense of immortality and infinity in the second dimension whilist avoiding the first dimension from freezing forever when someone simply doesn't want to come back because they don't want to die or maybe from other reasons.

I can't just let time in the first dimension freeze forever and cause the permanent immortalization of the death of the universe.

Comment: Have you seen the movie "Inception"?

Comment: @Alexander nope, it came out too long ago and never catched my attention

Comment: So the second dimension is personal, meaning no interaction between individuals? Without the possibility of causality there, it effectively doesn’t exist as far as the first dimension goes.

Comment: @StephenS yep, exactly, except you just never come back then the universe stops until you do, which could take forever.

Comment: @PythonProgrammersaresouless If time in the other dimension is truly infinite, our timeline doesn’t really stop; your return (after a possibly infinite amount of time) is just to the same point you left from. You only need to worry about coordinating timelines if the ratio is finite.

Answer (score 2):

**Time is faster in the secondary dimension.**

It is like the opposite of Faerie where Rip VanWinkle visits and decades pass in the human world.  In the secondary dimension (where all you can do is think?) time is fast.  Weeks pass in what would be seconds in the real world.

Nothing stops in the real world.  When your child returns after 1000 years, 13 minutes have passed and his dinner has gotten cold.

Answer (score 2):

Time must pass in both dimensions.  For a person in the secondary dimension to die if their body in the primary dimension dies, time must pass in the primary dimension so that an event there can affect the secondary.

However, the experience of primary dimension events would be very gradual in the secondary dimension.

Given that time must pass in the primary while in the secondary, the body in the primary would just be sitting and 'meditating'.  Its needs that can't be fulfilled by autonomic bodily functions would be going unmet.  It would also be unable to react to physical dangers until they begin to affect the body.

Time should be passing in the primary and secondary dimensions at a fixed ratio.  The higher the ratio is tipped toward the secondary, the more that a sense of immortality will apply.

If the ratio is 0:1 as is suggested in the question, then the problem is that the body cannot die while in the secondary dimension, and neither can individuals meet there, since each would be living in its own tiny slice of infinity.  As the OP has said that this would be undesirable, a ratio of 1:1000 or greater would provide the appropriate effect.

With a fixed, non-infinite ratio, the secondary dimension could be used for schooling, entertainment, or any number of other solitary or community purposes, since it would be possible to meet there.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so.

There isn't actually a problem here for fantasy purposes. It is in fact a standard trope.

If you consider the 3 standard physical dimensions, an object can move freely as far and as long as it likes in the 3rd dimension without affecting the other 2 in the slightest.

Considering time as a 4th dimension, the same could be true of your situation, your movement in dimensions 5,6,7 and 8 has absolutely no bearing on the position in 1,2,3 and 4.

*Time doesn't freeze, you're just not currently moving in that direction.*

Answer (score 1):

### When you go into the second dimension, you die *and* live on

**The issue (as I read it)**

So.. you have these folks in the first dimension, who miss their friends, or children, who left them to live in the second dimension. They can't really wait in the first dimension, where they will die.. so they will tend to follow. The second dimension will get overpopulated with everyone getting a private, lonely time line.. and the chance is near zero to meet ever again with anyone, on return. Hence an unbalanced story scenario. Question is: how to avoid having to freeze the 1st dimension to wait for the return ?

**Split the time line**

The child has a similar problem. It expects the time line in the 1st dimension to suspend. It would like to return and rejoin its parents, some time in the future. But same time, everything should roll on in the 1st dimension. So.. let's *split* these time lines. As soon as you enter the 2nd dimension, you enter a *separate* time line that has become personal, in *both* dimensions. The parents will be frozen, but only in the child's new time line.

In their own time line, your parents keep living and miss their child, who will never return. Whatever the child chooses to do, return or not, it won't ever return in *that* time line. The child has died there. Maybe out of grief, the parents will decide to follow their child into the 2nd dimension. But THAT will create *their own* second time line. Returning in the 1st dimension won't help, they will - again - not find  their child.

**Earth religions, heaven**

In fact, your concept touches death.. and heavens.. in Earth religions, we find back your 2nd dimension as heaven, you enter there after death. My solution resembles loss of a child, for the parents who lived on in their own time line (the one that was not suspended). For them, their child will have died and gone to heaven. When this child would hop to the second dimension and return many times, it will leave a lot of unlucky parents, in lots of abandoned time lines ! *Karma*..

Answer (score 0):

#### Time hasn't really stopped

You're thinking of it as though time has "frozen" in the normal world, but that hasn't actually happened.  What has happened is that the creature entering the immortal realm has created an orthogonal "branch" off of normal time - one where they have effectively accelerated their personal timestream infinitely, and can return at any point.

#### In infinite time, everything that can happen must happen

Assuming that people entering the immortal realm are truly immortal, there must ALWAYS be the possibility of coming back.  And since they can remain on that timeline forever, it is guaranteed that they will come back eventually. Although, their mind may broken down and destroyed by that point, in which case what comes back might be insane, or functionally dead, in which case their body will probably just go insane or comatose.  But it still has to come back eventually, so there is no point in normal time where the one who left is "still gone" - from the perspective of one in normal time, the creature's mind will simply have jumped forward in an instant, causing whatever changes that implies.

#### And it probably won't be long, because the immortal realm is boring

Since everyone who enters the immortal realm does so in their own personal timeline, it is essentially impossible for two different beings to meet in the immortal realm. The only way for this to happen would be if they entered at the *exact* same moment.  Similarly, all matter that enters the immortal realm through other means cannot accumulate, since it exists in a timeline orthogonal to normal time. Basically the immortal realm is a complete void (unless the magic that allows one to enter it also creates a world to live on).

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be done any way you like but its not hard science fiction. It would be a worthy challenge if you had the intention to make it harder sci-fi and regarding the time dimension, since its not been done in thousands of years since the greek tragedies. as far as I know.

Time and movement is just an illusion.  We are 3 dimensional beings that extend into the 4th as our time.  Thus in 4d, The past present and future for a 3d sentient being exist simultaneously, only he has memories of only of direction in the time dimension.  If you could run a 3d (slice) through the 4d over your time like in a movie editor or game replay, you would see your birth growth and death.  Why do we think time passes?  For many physicists , ones capable of generating theory like E=mc2, as in Einstein, who were doing practical physics,  to them  it doesn't pass, when you add a dimension to account for the illusion of movement it contains all the information regarding the changes , thus freezing the model.   Why do we think time passes? Well we merely remember the past and have yet to learn of the future because it takes generates heat to think and form memories, heat needs space to dissipate, so we remember when the universe was smaller an hotter, as we always think it expands, when in fast is just -IS-. could be contracting.. Its not moving at all. we will always "think" its expanding but we are already dead somewhere. See Hawkings a brief history of Time for this idea well explained using a 2D creature with 3D as his spacetime, for easy visualization of the continuum.

This is Einstein's original universe model though its not well agreed on, people don't like the idea as they did in the 1920s when Einstein was a famous public figure.  But the idea of fate and lack of free will is as old as the Greeks and has been used for entertainment. The Tragedies of Aeschylus as he consulted the oracle, and tried to elude his fate but did as he pondered and fretted, receive death from above because a bird dropped a clam on his head,  allude to such advanced science as Einstein 1905 paper and his Math professor Minkowski taught.  Einstein himself mentioned that time is an illusion soon after his best friend died, After the death of his old friend, Einstein said "Now Besso has departed from this strange world a little ahead of me. That means nothing. People like us ... know that the distinction between past, present and future is only a stubbornly persistent illusion."    But i warn you most people do not find this treatment entertaining in fact quite disturbing.   Physicist have come up with multiverse and other but those have never yielded things like Atom bombs, telescopic proof, or anything useful.    I guess it feels good to believe u have choice, but if it comforted Einstein when his friend died a few weeks before him, and if the Greek tragedian's could handle the truth, the audiences entertained, perhaps some harder science regarding fate and dimensionality could be made into entertainment rather than pseudoscience or less logical, modern thinking on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Compact Spacetime Directions**

[image]

I understand these guys have the ability to *press pause* for however long they like. During this time, from their perspective, nothing moves, including their own body, and they can only think.

Here is some string theory mumbo-jumbo about how it works. The universe has extra **compact dimensions**. Rather than space being 3-dimensional it is 4-dimensional except the 4th dimension is not an infinite straight line like the others. It is a very small circle that is too small to see under normal conditions.

In the three-dimensional universe everything has 3 positions. You can give $x,y,z$ coordinates for objects, and each of those numbers can be anywhere on the real number line. In the four-dimensional universe everything has $x,y,z$ and $c$ coordinates where $c$ can be any position on the circle.

Think of an ant living on an infinite (very thin) tube rather than an infinitely thin straight line. The ant is much bigger than the circle that goes around the tube, so she cannot tell the difference. An ant moving around the tube seems to be standing still.

When you go into the thinking zone, you simply change the direction you mind travels through spacetime. Rather than moving along the tube with the body, It moves in circles around the outside of the tube.

The mind can do as many circuits as it wants before returning to the body. The number of circuits translate to subjective time spent in the thinking zone.

Since the mind moves around, and not along the tube, it can return to the body at the same time it left.